# laravel 5.1 login not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I used laravel 5.1 authentication for login . but `Auth::attempt($credentials)` returns false always!

I used the following route to create user:

```
Route::get('newuser', function () {
  return User::create([
    'username' => 'admin',
    'email' => 'admin@gmail.com',
    'password' => Hash::make('123'),
  ]);
});
```

I added a simple postLogin function to override this function in AuthController:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request) {
    $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);
    if(Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return 'ok';
    }
    return 'nok';
}
```

getCredentials is laravel function with this content:

```
protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'password');
}
```

Comment: can you edit the question and post the $credential code which you are using?

Comment: ofcourse, question updated!

Comment: Is it typo `Hash:make('123')` I think it should be `Hash::make('123')`

Comment: oh, sorry, it was a typo and I edited that!

Comment: Please give us the contents of `getCredentials()` :)

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons for this thing.
I would suggest you to check the lenght of the password column in phpMyAdmin in your user table.

Change the password column to maximum lenght in database in the table where you are storing the password.

Another I would suggest you try with following code if it is working.

```
 public function postLogin()
   {
    // Login credentials
    $credentials = array(
        'username'    => 'admin@gmail.com',
        'password' => '123',
    );
   // Authenticate the user
   if (Auth::attempt($credentials))
{
    return 'ok';
}
else{
    return "failed";
}
```

Hope it would help.

1. Dont forget to change the password column length in database,Change it to maximum.
2. Change the password datatype to LONGTEXT with length to maximun or 1000.

Last and important is to delete all the records from the table and restart the process,because the priviously saved passed was saved with another lenght and beacuse of that the currunt hashed password does not matches the old one.

So truncate that table and try it again.

Comment: I changed password column length in database to 255 char and test your code but the result is same!

Comment: Change the data type to LONGTEXT and set the lengh to 1000 just try this once.Can see the edited anwers this might help you.

Comment: it's not from password because `Hash::check($credentials['password'], $hashPass)` code returns true, where $hashPass filled with database password.

Comment: Seriously dude? The password field should by a LONGTEXT of 1000 char?? What kind of solution to his problem is yours??

Comment: As per answer most of the login auth issues even in laravel 4 and laravel 5 are because of password encryption,Which is saved to database not completely because small length saved in database password field, When trying to auth the encrypted long password does not matches to the incomplete password saved in database password field, I have tested the code and I am able to auth successfully by changing the size in database.I faced this issue both in laravel 4 and laravel 5.According to your experience if it is really wrong then I would really wait for your answer on this.Pls share your solution.

Comment: It is recommended  to keep 60+ size vachar on password field,For the safer size I used long text.Please follow this link 'http://laravel.io/forum/01-09-2015-authattempt-command-always-fails-using-laravel-4216?page=1' on same issue.